Failed to apply plugin [id 'forge'] I don't know what to do
when i try sysns gradle changes in intellij idea i get this error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\dimam\Downloads\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src\crafttable16\build.gradle' line: 14

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'crafttable16'.



Failed to apply plugin [id 'forge']
You must set the Minecraft Version!
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

CONFIGURE FAILED in 0s
How can I fix the error?
I'm a newbie and I don't know what to do.
I am writing from a google translator and
I used microsoft copilot to help but only more errors occur or nothing changes at all.
gradle-4.5
my build.gradle:
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name = 'forge'
            url = 'http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'forge'

version = "1.0"
group = "com.example"
archivesBaseName = "examplemod"

minecraft {
    version = "1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10"
    runDir = "run"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = 'forge'
        url = 'http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // добавьте ваши зависимости здесь
}

processResources {
    inputs.property "version", project.version
    inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version

    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include 'mcmod.info'
        expand 'version': project.version, 'mcversion': project.minecraft.version
    }

    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude 'mcmod.info'
    }
} 


